# Adapter deployment failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/core/wink-providers

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-adapters

We'are using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0.0-20150729-1801 with eclipse 4.4.2 on Mac 10.10.5, and making a Java adapter.

When deploying the adapter, we got the following error message, and failed to deploy the adapter. How can we solve the problem?

> Adapter deployment failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   META-INF/core/wink-providers

Comment: Start by providing the full exception log from the server view in eclipse or the messages.log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the messages.log that was sent via email, the issue IMO may happen due to the spaces/sign in the path to the Eclipse workspace:

> /Volumes/**Mac
>   HD**/job/*****+******/***/worklight/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/ ...

This is likely happening due to the "+" sign in the path. It is a special character and as such would need to be escaped in order for the full path to be properly parsed. This would need to happen on the Liberty (application server) layer and so may not be directly related to MobileFirst.

I would suggest to either rename or create a new workspace, w/out a space or the "+" sign anywhere in the path.